# Import SQL server database using batch

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, import, scripting

I need to import a database into a SQL Server instance using a batch script and the database is provided by an sql file.

How can I do This?

The SQL file was generated by the SQL Server management studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has a command line utility called [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx).  It will let you do things like run scripts or restore a database backup.  The -i parameter allows you to specify an input file.

There is also an article [here](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sqlcmd.htm) that has a quick intro to SQLCMD.

Comment: Would it be something like this? sqlcmd -U mario -P mario -i file.sql

Comment: I believe so but you'll probably also need to specify the server (-S) and maybe a few other things depending on your situation.  Type 'sqlcmd /?' on the command line to get a full list of the options.  It may take a couple of tries to get it right so try it first on a development server if you can.